# IF statement bug?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

How come this IF statement doesn't work properly?

code:

```
function testFunction() 
{
    var cnt = 0;    
    alert((!cnt > 1 ? '<= 1' : '> 1'));
}

testFunction();
```

Not matter what value **cnt** is set to, it keeps going for the else statement. Could someone explain me why and how?

Fiddle in action:

> https://jsfiddle.net/hfagyf66/1/

Edit: I even parseInt variable **cnt**, still not clue on why this is happening.

Comment: `!cnt > 1` is the same as `(!cnt) > 1` and `!0 = 1` and since `1` is **not** *strictly greater* than `1`, you get false. Change it to `!(cnt > 1)`.

Comment: Weird wording of the question since you claim is goes for the `else` statement, yet there is no `else` statement in the question.  I presume you mean it executes the second option in the ternary?

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: @Bakuriu It even enters the 'false' statement when cnt is set to > 1 (50 for example).

Comment: Note that in other programming languages you would be right. For example in python `not cnt > 1` would mean `not (cnt > 1)` because logical operators have lower precedence, but unfortunately in C-like languages unary operators have the highest precedence (usually).

Comment: @Testuser075 Because when `cnt > 0` then `!cnt = 0`. `!` is not, numbers `> 0` are "true" and thus `!` turns them into false i.e. `0`, while `0` becomes true which is `1`. In both cases `0` and `1` are not strictly greater than `1`.

Answer (score 1):

`!` operator has very high priority. Therefore javascript first evaluates `!cnt` which is `0` or `1` and therefore the condition `> 1` could be never satisfied.